# Django 1.3 rc1 and CSS

Tags: css, django, static

This is my configuration:

```
project_root
- (init, urls, settings, manage etc.).py
- templates
- - - <html files>
- - - <css files>
- - - <images>
- mainapp
```

**my settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
...
STATIC_ROOT = 'c:/static_collect/'
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'c:/django-projects/myproject/mainapp/templates',
)
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ('c:/django-projects/myproject/mainapp/templates',)
```

my template references CSS files with {{ STATIC_URL}}style.css.

Everything works in development server. I view my CSS, static images and everything else.

Now I'm preparing to deploy a project, so I'm experimenting a little, before buying a hosting. Launched *manage.py collectstatic* and all of my static files in STATICFILES_DIRS were correctly copied to c:/static_collect.

I switched Debug = False to Debug = True. And my website doesn't load the stylesheet. I'm going crazy on this... templates are loaded but static files are simply not reachable.

Are not you allowed to put Debug=False in the development server?
Will it be solved once I put the project on a real production server?
Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you actually configured Apache (or whatever) to serve the static files from c:/static_collect/?

Comment: I'm only using the bundled Django development server. This is the reason of my question: "Are not you allowed to put Debug=False in the development server?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static files aren't added to the url patterns when debug is set to False.  See [staticfiles/urls.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/staticfiles/urls.py):

```
if settings.DEBUG and not urlpatterns:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

You'll need to setup apache to serve the files, or add the urlpatterns yourself when debug is False (not recommended).

Comment: Ok. If I understand your answer, you are telling me to turn off Debug only in case of real deployment, right?

Comment: Yes, the only time to turn off debug during development is to test 500 and 404 pages.  In that case you can just add the urlpatterns manually to your `urls.py` file.